# Solving for Unknown in Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, transpose

What number $b$ in 
\begin{bmatrix} 3 & b \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
makes $A = Q\Lambda Q^T$  possible?

Comment: what is $A$?  Is it the matrix [[3,b],[1,0]]. ?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Notice that if $A = Q\Lambda Q^T$ then $A^T=A$.

**UPDATE**

I am assuming $\Lambda$ is real-valued. If you assume $\Lambda$ is diagonal, $A$ must be symmetric so $b=1$. Without any assumptions on $\Lambda$, as Laray indicated, $A$ must be normal...

Comment: So that would make b=-1 ?

Comment: Try again... symmetric, not skew-symmetric.

Comment: A must be normal. There is no need for A to be symmetric. There is one more step to get there.

Comment: @Laray updated, thank you

Comment: Hmm ok, I'll keep working at it then.

Comment: I would put wording about $\Lambda$ haven real entries. That will enforce symmetry. With complex entries, there are other possibilities of normality.

Comment: So I worked through it, would 1 work?/

Comment: @user9501082 yes